# JSON parse string having Apostrophe (Single Quote)

Tags: javascript

How do i parse the following string

```
var a = JSON.parse('[' + '{"NoteName":"it's my life","UserId":"100","NoteActive":true,"UserEmail":"admin@dev.xrc.com","CreatedDate":"8/13/2012 1:47:35 PM"}' + ']');
```

Comment: Why are you creating JSON by hand instead of using `JSON.stringify`? Then you wouldn't have to worry about details like this, it's handled automatically for you.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with parsing JSON. Your question is basically about how to put an apostrophe into a string when you're using apostrophe as the delimiter around the string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have just to escape a single quote `it\'s`

```
var a = JSON.parse('[' + '{"NoteName":"it\'s my life","UserId":"100","NoteActive":true,"UserEmail":"admin@dev.xrc.com","CreatedDate":"8/13/2012 1:47:35 PM"}' + ']');
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `it's` with `it\'s`

```
'[' + '{"NoteName":"it\'s my life","UserId":"100","NoteActive":true,"UserEmail":"admin@dev.xrc.com","CreatedDate":"8/13/2012 1:47:35 PM"}' + ']'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape (interpret solely as characters) quote marks using backslash.
"\"" or '\''